# How to solve "cannot open shared object" problem while opening subprocess within apache

Tags: django, apache, qt, shared

I run a web application in apache.
My application try to execute a executable written by QT.

But I always encounter "cannot open shared object libQtWebkit.so: No such file or directory" error.

I can run this executable in shell without any problem. 
I tried set LD_LIBRARY_PATH but still not working.

How can I set shared library path for apache to make it run this executable?

Thanks!

(Note: for more detail, my web application is written by django which run in mod_wsgi, I try to run my executable file with subprocess.Popen. This executable is written by QT 4.6.3, located on $HOME/lib/qt (not system installed QT version), I set QTDIR and LD_LIBRARAY_PATH, but not working)

Comment: does it work with the django development server (manage.py runserver)?

Comment: it works (runserver), it can load shared libraries without any problem and work very well.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I did face the same problem and got the solution from http://www.computing.net/answers/linux/error-in-loading-shared-libraries-/16460.html

Say, Apache fails to load xyz.so file. Go to your terminal, and locate it:

```
locate xyz.so
```

And say you get as output:

```
/path/to/xyz.so
```

Add this path (`/path/to`) in the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file. Then run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Now restart Apache server and check.